# How to Perform Bottom-Up Parsing for a Given CFG and Input String?

Tags: parsing, tree, context-free-grammar, automata

I am currently working on a project that involves parsing arithmetic expressions using a context-free grammar (CFG). I have the following CFG for generating arithmetic expressions:

```
E -> E + T
E -> T
T -> T * F
T -> F
F -> ( E )
F -> id
```

My task is to perform a bottom-up parsing tree for a specific input string: "id * ( id + id )".

I'm a bit confused about how to go about it. Can someone provide a step-by-step explanation or code example on how to construct the bottom-up parsing tree for this input string using the given CFG? Your help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the expected output? What is the tree data structure? Is it object oriented? You have a programming language in mind? lisp? python? c++?

Comment: There's "bottom-up parse" and "parse tree", but there isn't really any such thing as "bottom-up parse tree". When your grammar is unambiguous (as in this case), there is exactly one parse tree for any given string in the language; a bottom-up parse and a top-down parse aren't going to result in different parse trees. My guess is that your task is to construct (probably by hand) the parse tree for the given input string, using a bottom-up method. Does that sound correct?